# .htaccess mode_rewrite match percent symbol problem

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So i want to know how can i make it that if someone asks for the page: www.mydomain.com/**%D7%90%D7%91%D7%90.php**

he would get to the page: www.mydomain.com/**D790D791D790.php** (without the percentages) but his browser url will show the first page he asked for (with no redirection).

I've found out that the URI is escaping the % symbol to it's hex value %25 and because i don't have access to the httpd file i'm not able to switch on "noescape|NE".

So now i need to use mode_rewrite to match %25 and replace it with nothing, or even replace it with a dash but i have no clue how to make the regex, can someone help?